# Proof that fixed points of a null field are zero

Tags: fourier-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

In this context, a *null field* means a field constructed of planar waves $e^{I k_{\mu} x^{\mu}}$ that satisfy the null condition $k_{\mu} k^{\mu} = 0 \implies c^2 k^2 = \omega^2 $

Suppose we have a scalar field $V$ (which can be acoustic pressure, or a scalar electric potential) that is a solution of the wave equation

$$\Box V(x,y,z,t) = 0$$

I am wondering if a fixed (non-oscillating) minimum (or maximum) of field potential $\textbf{r}_0=(r_x,r_y,r_z)$ can be constructed with incoming waveforms on the boundary, or if it can be shown mathematically that is not possible

The [Khirchhoff integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff_integral_theorem) provides certain ability to control fields inside a volume with sources on the boundary (holophony and acoustic levitation are based on this principle). But I am not sure what are the general restrictions that have the waveforms, and how those restrictions evolve with time

I tried to build an argument assuming that the waveform is made by finite Fourier elements (zero frequency / constant terms are not present as they are physically irrelevant )

$$f(x,t)=\sum_{k,\omega} \hat{f}(k,\omega) e^{-I(kx-\omega t)}$$

Assume that $x_0$ is a fixed point with $f(x_0,t) \ne 0$, $f_x(x_0,t) =0$, $f_{xx}(x_0,t)>0$, and finally that

$$\frac{\partial^{n} f(x,t)}{\partial t^{n-1} \partial x} \Bigg|_{x=x_0} = 0 $$

for all $n > 1$. This last condition ensures that the point stays a minimum over time. If these conditions are not satisfied exactly, $x_0$ will be a stable minimum only over some amount of time.

Now the part of the argument that leaves me unsure is to assume that since the function is only made of a finite sum of such planar waves, after taking enough derivatives I will have enough equations to prove that all coefficients should be zero, which would contradict some of the hypothesis $f(x_0,t) \ne 0$, $f_x(x_0,t) =0$.. etc.

Can this argument be improved? Also it doesn't say much if approximate fixed points can last for a period of time (probably yes, but I don't know how to prove that either)

**A motivating example** for this problem would be that, if you could create a stable minimum of electric potential with electromagnetic waves, you could sustain pseudo-electrostatic confinement potential for charged ions in a prescribed point that is otherwise devoid of matter, like those created with virtual grids in [Fansworth fusors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor)